# PostSharp: How to prevent double aspect invoking when calling base method?

Tags: postsharp

For example:

```
class BaseClass : IDisposable {
   [LogMethod]
   public BaseClass() {
   }

   [LogMethod] // This is OnMethodBoundaryAspect with MulticastInheritance.Strict
   public virtual void Dispose() { // overridden method
   }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass {
    public SubClass() : base() { // this doesn't lead to double LogMethod invoking
    }

    public override void Dispose() { // overriding method
      base.Func(); // this leads to double LogMethod invoking
    }
}
```

Problem is that `base.Func()` leads to double aspect invoking. Is it possible to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the best way. I just ignore logging on overridden methods.

```
    void IInstanceScopedAspect.RuntimeInitializeInstance() {
        IsEnabled = !IsOverridden( method, instance );
    }

    private static bool IsOverridden(MethodBase method, object instance) {
        if (method is MethodInfo method_) return instance.GetType().HasOverridingMethod( method_ );
        return false;
    }


    public static bool HasOverridingMethod(this Type type, MethodInfo baseMethod) {
        return type.GetOverridingMethod( baseMethod ) != null;
    }
    public static MethodInfo GetOverridingMethod(this Type type, MethodInfo baseMethod) {
        var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod;
        return type.GetMethods( flags ).FirstOrDefault( i => baseMethod.IsBaseMethodOf( i ) );
    }
    private static bool IsBaseMethodOf(this MethodInfo baseMethod, MethodInfo method) {
        return baseMethod.DeclaringType != method.DeclaringType && baseMethod == method.GetBaseDefinition();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without changing the code or making changes to the aspect itself.

The reason is that PostSharp transforms method code. It adds calls to the aspect to the method body of BaseClass.Dispose and to the method body of `SubClass.Dispose`. Since `BaseClass.Dispose` calls `SubClass.Dispose`, the aspect will get executed for both.

To disable the aspect when `BaseClass.Dispose` is called from `SubClass.Dispose`, you need to pass the information about its caller to the base method. Without changing the code (which would break the purpose of the aspect), it's possible by changing the aspect to use `AsyncLocal` or `[ThreadStatic]` to pass the state between aspect instances.

Comment: May be it would be better to determine in `RuntimeInitialize` either aspect is nested or not? Only I don't understand how to do it?

Comment: What if each sub aspect will disable parent aspect in runtime? Only question: how to find parent aspect? Is there a list of aspects?

Comment: There is no built-in list of aspects, you'd need to implement registration in `RuntimeInitialize` yourself. Aspect instances are by default per declaration, i.e. `BaseClass.Dispose` has one global instance of the aspect. Disabling aspect for `BaseClass.Dispose` would disable it also for other implementations of `BaseClass`. You can use instance-scoped aspects (see https://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-lifetime ), but it would add performance and memory overhead. FYI when you apply an aspect to `BaseClass.ctor`, it will not be multicast to `SubClass.ctor` because constructors are not virtual members

Comment: Why does `method.GetCustomAttributes<LogAttribute>( true )` not return inherited attributes?

Comment: It would be a greate solution.

Comment: @wishmaster35 By default `MulticastAttribute` are not persisted. You need to use `MulticastAttributeUsageAttribute.PersistMetadata` as described here https://doc.postsharp.net/multicast-reflection in order to have multicasted attributes available at runtime (this is mainly to prevent assemblies with globally multicasted attributes bloating in size too much).

Comment: And you must use  `[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true )]`